# TokBox Controller / Model Ruby

Tags: ruby-on-rails, opentok, tokbox

**UPDATE**: I have solved the NilClass issue! Thanks!

Now I am having a problem with:

```
unknown attribute 'sessionId' for Room.
```

**SOLVED**I am currently having some issues where my code is telling me I have an error of "undefined method `create_session' for nil:NilClass" on line 9. I will provide the files.

This is the specific line:

```
   @new_room = Room.new(strong_param)
```

**rooms_controller.rb**

```
class RoomsController < ApplicationController
require "opentok"
before_filter :config_opentok,:except => [:index]
  def index
    @rooms = Room.where(:public => true).order("created_at DESC")
    @new_room = Room.new
  end

def create
  session = @opentok.create_session :media_mode => :routed
  params[:room][:sessionId] = session.session_id

  @new_room = Room.new(strong_param)

  respond_to do |format|
    if @new_room.save
      format.html { redirect_to(“/party/”+@new_room.id.to_s) }
    else
      format.html { render :controller => ‘rooms’, :action => “index” }
    end
  end
end

def party
  @room = Room.find(params[:id])

  @tok_token = @opentok.generate_token @room.sessionId 
end

  private
  def config_opentok
    if @opentok.nil?
     @opentok = OpenTok::OpenTok.new ########, "#########################################"
    end
  end
    def strong_param
      params.require(:room).permit(:name,:sessionId)
  end
end
```

**rooms.rb** (Models)

```
class Room < ActiveRecord::Base
end
```

I've tried several different modifications to these files to make my program work. I can get the listing page to work but once I try and actually create a new room, I receive this error message.

Look forward to any advice you can provide.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are missing the `before_filter :config_opentok,:except => [:index]` line from the blog post in your previous post (https://railsfornovice.wordpress.com/2013/01/01/video-chatting-in-ruby-on-rails/)